# Heat trace asymptotic coefficients for conformal metrics $\widetilde{g}=e^{f}g$ surfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, conformal-geometry

As is well known $\sum e^{-\lambda_{k}t}\approx(4\pi t)^{dim(M)/2}\sum a_{j}t^{j}$, where $a_{j}$ are geometric properties of manifold M.

Moreover, the arbitrary order coefficients don't have closed form (though some progress in "Combinatorics of heat kernel coefficients").

However, say $\widetilde{g}=e^{f}g$ where g=Euc. or Sph. metric, then the curvature terms are simpler in dimension 2. Are the $a_{j}$ coefficients known explicitly for such surfaces?

Comment: This family should include hyperbolic surfaces, so I doubt it. Some results on the general question are in McKean-Singer 1967 (e.g., Euler characteristic is audible). They indicate the computations for higher-order coefficients are very difficult. I believe there is also a study of this made in Buser's book *Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces*, though I do not have it handy to check. Another reference is Chavel's book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* although I do not recall explicit computations for conformal metrics.

Comment: I don't know how much is the following fact related to your question or interest; but the conformal variations of the zeta regularized determinant (which is defined precisely using the (analytic continuation of the) series $\sum e^{-\lambda t}$) are expressed by the Polyakov formula.